# Correlation between amount of rows and amount columns in database performance

Tags: sql, performance

Is there a correlation between the amount of rows/number of columns used and it's impact within the (MS)SQL database?

**A little more background:**
We have to store lots of data from measurement devices. These devices ping a string with data back to us around 100 times a day. These strings contains +- 300 fields. Assume we have 100 devices in operation that means we get 10000 records back every day. At our back-end we split these data strings and have to put these into the database. When these data strings are fixed that means we add each days around 10000 new rows into the database. No big deal.

Whatsoever, the contents of these data strings may change during time. There are two options we are considering:

- Using vertical tables to store the data dynamically
- Using horizontal tables and add a new column now and then when it's needed.

From the perspective of ease we'd like to choose for the first approach. Whatsoever, that means we're adding 100*100*300=3000000 rows each day. Data has to be stored 1 year and a month (395 days) so  then we're around 1.2 billion rows. Not calculated the expected growth.

Is it from a performance perspective smarter to use a 'vertical' or a 'horizontal' approach?

When choosing for the 'vertical' solution, how can we actual optimize performance by using PK's/FK's wisely?

When choosing for the 'horizontal' solution, are there recommendations for adding columns to the table?

Comment: Storing more columns and less rows saves a lot of per-row storage space. If the fields in each row are mostly the same the approach with many columns is going to be superior.; You can add new columns as an O(1) operation if you like.

Comment: An idea may be to create a revision 2 extension table with the additionnal columns.

Comment: You could consider partitioning the table by day / month. Which database do you use (SQL Server / Oracle ...)?

Comment: `the contents of these data strings may change during time.` Do you mean, the *values* change over time and you need to maintain history ? In that case: do *all* fields change, or just one, or do updates appear *group-wise* ?

Comment: First, thanks for the usefull answers already!

@JosephB We're using SQL Server.

Comment: @wildplasser Can be everything. The data string is practically a space separated string of values. Values can move up several fields, fields can be added or removed. But that's no problem whatsoever. That's all stuff which can be handled in business logic.

Comment: No, that *is* the question. If the items change sparsely over time, you'll be convicted to split the fields into an EAV-like model. (unless updates are very rare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can tune a table more for inserts (or any DML) or for queries. Improving one side comes at the expense of the other. Usually, it's a balancing act.

First of all, 10K inserts a day is not really a large number. Sure, it's not insignificant, but it doesn't even come close to what would be considered "large" nowadays So, while we don't want to make inserts downright sluggish, this gives you some wiggle room.

Creating an index on the device id and/or entry timestamp will do some logical partitioning of the data for you. The exact makeup of your index(es) will depend on your queries. Are you looking for all entries for a given date or date range? Then index the timestamp column. Are you looking for all entries received from a particular device? Then index the device id column. Are you looking for entries from a particular device on a particular date or date range or sorted by the date? Then create an index on both columns.

So if you ask for the entries for device x on date y, then you are going out to the table and looking only at the rows you need. The fact that the table is much larger than the small subset you query is incidental. It's as if the rest of the table doesn't even exist. The total size of the table need not be intimidating.

Another option: As it looks like the data is written to the table and never altered after that, then you may want to create a data warehouse schema for the data. New entries can be moved to the warehouse every day or several times a day. The point is, the warehouse schema can have the data sliced, diced, quartered and cubed to make queries much more efficient. So you can have the existing table tuned for more efficient inserts and the warehouse tuned for more efficient queries. That is, after all, what data warehouses are for.

You also imply that some of each entry is (or can be) duplicated from one entry to the next. See if you can segment the data into three types:

Type 1: Data that never changes (the device id, for example)
    Type 2: Data that rarely changes
    Type 3: Data that changes often

Now all you have is a normalization problem, something a lot easier to solve. Let's say the row is equally split between the types. So you have one table with 100 rows of 33 columns. That's it. It never changes. Linked to that is a table with at least 100 rows of 33 columns but maybe several new rows are added each day. Finally, linked to the second table a table with rows of 33 columns that possibly grows by the full 10K every day.

This minimizes the grow-space required by the online database. The warehouse could then denormalize back to one huge table for ease of querying.

Comment: Do you have some resources explaining the data warehouse schema?

Comment: Just google "oltp vs olap" and stand back. Get coffee.

Answer (score 2):

I have a vertical DB with 275 million rows in the "values" table.  We took this approach because we couldn't accurately define the schema at the outset either.  Inserts are fantastic.  Selects suck.  Too be fair we throw in a couple of extra doohickies the typical vertical schema doesn't have to deal with.

Have a search for EAV aka Entity Attribute Value models.  You'll find a lot of heat on both sides of the debate.  Too good articles on making it work are

- [What is so bad about EAV, anyway?](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway)
- [dave’s guide to the eav](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/articles/12117.aspx)

My guess is these sensors don't just start sending you extra fields.  You have to release new sensors or sensor code for this to happen.  That's your chance to do change control on your schema and add the extra columns.  If external parties can connect sensors without notifying you this argument is null and void and you may be stuck with an EAV.

For the horizontal option you can split tables putting the frequently-used columns in one table and the less-used in a second; both tables have the same primary key values so you can link less-used to more-used columns.  Also you can use RDBMS's built-in partitioning functionality to split each day's (or week's or month's) data for the others'.